# Was there a book written about jazz in the Donetsk region?

Tags: ukrainian-language, voroshilovgrad, serhiy-zhadan

In *Voroshilovgrad*, the Presbyter gave Herman a book called *The Development and Decline of Jazz in the Donetsk Region*. Olga expressed some degree of surprise that they played jazz there at all, and Herman didn't seem to have been aware of it either.

Is there actually a jazz scene there? Also, is this a real book?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Ukrainian it is "*Історія і занепад джазу у Донецькому басейні*". When googling this, you can find only two relevant texts (both in Ukrainian). I understand that it is Zhadan's own way to praise this jazz theme. That is, there is no such book really.